# Form Validation Callback With Extra Parameter from Array?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Asking about codeigniter 3 form validation with callback.
Form validation - thats validating an array of data - in this case a group of products - and one rule has a callback. Like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('productid[]', 'Product ID', 'required');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('productsku[]', 'Product SKU', 'callback_sku_check');
```

and then the callback goes to the method: sku_check($str)

All that works fine, churns through and checks an array of product skus no problem. Now is there a way to pass the correct Product ID from the array to the callback method? So i could have

```
sku_check($str,$productid)
```

where the product id matches the specific sku in the array?

Comment: in your `productsku[]` you can use the `productid` as your index so you can just break it down in your `sku_check($str)` without asking for `$productid`

Comment: @kiong - how? show some code please.